# extract numbers in sequential: python

Tags: python, sequential

I'm a novice coding learner. 
I am trying to extract numbers only in sequential from the list.

for example, my list is:

```
s = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
```

from this list I want only the numbers in sequential:

```
6,7,8,9,10, 13,14,15
```

so, I have the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
s = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]


for i in s:
    if s[i+1] - s[i] == 1:
        print(s[i])
```

could you give me some idea?  Thank you.

Comment: Try to `print(i)` and you will see the problem

Comment: you are taking for i in s: this will select a number like 2, 4,6 from your list not index.

Comment: Read [pythonforbeginners.:Lists](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

you are looping over the items of the list instead of the indices of these items. To loop over the indices use:

```
if s[1] - s[0] == 1:
    print(s[0])
for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if s[i] - s[i-1] == 1: 
        print(s[i])
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. However in this case the final number from the sequential doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this question. thank you all for commenting.

```
s = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
a = []
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i] - s[i+1] == -1:
        a. append(s[i])
        a. append(s[i+1])

print(set(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the `list s` storing the results in `set res` and at the end, if I want the results **sorted**, I would apply the `sorted function on res` to get the output.

Here is some code.

```
s= [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
res = set()
for i, num in enumerate(s[:-1]):
    if num+1 == s[i+1]:
        res = res.union({num} )           
        res = res.union({s[i+1]})
print(sorted(res))
print(res)
```

And the output is:

```
>>> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15}
```

Keep in mind that `set`s are **NOT** sorted even if they appear to be sorted. This is because `set`s **DO NOT** support `index`es. So if you want your results sorted, make sure to apply the `sorted` function to be on the safe side.